# Using SQL Server stored procedure from MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have found answers on this site, but none of them work. I am trying to return results from a simple stored procedure in an ASP.NET MVC web api.

This works:

```
 ctx.Database.SqlQuery <model>("StoredProc 1251");
```

But, I have always though it was poor practice to include the parameters inline like that.

Nothing else I have tried works- here are some examples:

```
//Assuming this variable:
int intValue;
intValue = 1251;

// None of these variations that I have tried work:
ctx.Database.SqlQuery<model>("StoredProc @intValue= {0}", intValue);
ctx.Database.SqlQuery<model>("StoredProc @IntValue", 1251);
ctx.Database.SqlQuery<model>("StoredProc @IntValue", new SqlParameter("@IntValue",1251);
 //And 6 or 7 others
```

All give me a useless SQL Server error message:

> Incorrect syntax near SP

What is the correct syntax for this?

Can't answer my own question yet, but I found answer:

Found the correct syntax, or at least one correct option for the syntax, elsewhere in stackoverflow- this site really rocks- I almost always find me answer here!

```
var myInt = new SqlParameter("@IntVal", SqlDbType.Int);
pMeme_ck.Value = 1251;
return ctx.Database.SqlQuery<ClaimSummary>("EXEC StoredProcedureName @IntVal=@IntVal", myInt);
```

Comment: what is `SP`?  Stored procedure?  If so, try `EXEC SP @intValue`.

Comment: Yes- but I actually need to return the result- not sure how I would use exec in this case: return ctx.Database.SqlQuery<model>( StoredOroc @intVal= {0}", myIntVal);

Answer (score 0):

You're executing a raw SQL query against  your database.  You need to execute the stored procedure.

```
ctx.Database.SqlQuery<model>("EXEC StoredProc @IntValue", 1251);
```

**UPDATE**:
You may also want to try executing:

```
ctx.<EntityType>.SqlQuery("StoredProc @IntValue", 1251);
```

(Replace  with the type name of your entity being returned.)

This should return EntityTypes which is returned by the stored proc "StoredProc".  This [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) limited MSDN documentation.

Comment: david, Thanks for your response, unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work either: On the first way I got: Must declare the scalar variable "@intValue" The second options does not seem to be valid syntax at all, and will not compile.

Comment: I never used this before.  If you use `@p0` instead of `@intValue`, do you get the same error?